# Importing a module from the same level

Tags: python, flask

I have the following directory structure:

```
src/
  app.py
  promisebot/
    __init__.py
    models/
      __init__.py
      user.py
```

I can't seem to import users from models with the following:

```
from os import environ as env
from flask import Flask

from .promisebot.models import User

app = Flask(__name__)
```

`flask run` returns a cryptic

```
Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised.
```

Comment: Are you executing the 'run' command in the 'src' directory?

Comment: Yep, I'm running it the top level.

Comment: It looks like a circular import bug. Are you importing 'app' into your model? Can you add the content of the user.py file?

Comment: @kevic, you're right. I think I have a circular import. Refactoring a bit now.